# Is there any way to merge documents together?

Tags: 2013, document

I'm working with a policy committee that's transitioning from a centrally-managed document to distributed management (that is, they plan to split IT responsibilities off to a separate working group, plant services responsibilities to another, etc).

I've been asked to come up with a way to merge their documents together into one large work product. Is there any way to do this in SharePoint 2013? I'm skimming over some technical details they'd have to supply, because my research suggests that this isn't possible.

Comment: Are you asking about merging document libraries or merging multiple files into a single file?  If the latter, what type of files?

Comment: The latter. These documents would all be Word documents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint has the Word Automation Services that can do this with custom code.  There is a good example of how to use the services in this MSDN Magazine article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff797985.aspx

There wouldn't be a way to do this without code from a SharePoint perspective.

Comment: I'm guessing the same idea is applicable in 2013 here. From a governance perspective, where we're currently trying to minimize the features in our rollout, would you view this as a customization that would require a lot of support?

Comment: I suppose that depends on how you implement it.  If you simply have a button that merges all Word docs in a library, it probably wouldn't be too difficult to support it.