# How to merge two file documents in single file?

Tags: 2013, document

I want to merge two or more document files of Document library in single document file using SharePoint 2013. How I will achieve this? Please help me.
In advance Thank you.

Comment: Kindly refer this post..http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98465/is-there-any-way-to-merge-documents-together

Comment: Is there also any workaround for Excel files?

Comment: No. Right now I just want to merge two or more word files in a single file. But I am not getting this output even with the above link.